# Use Symfony service in phpunit

Tags: symfony, service, phpunit

I would like to test my DAO service.

The problem is that nothing append when I execute my test. No test is executed.
But I'm sur that the config file phpunit.xml.dist is ok, beause if I make a mistake in the "use" line for exemple, the test show me the errors.

So I need your help..

My first test :

```
namespace RepositoryBundle\Tests\DAO;

use RepositoryBundle\Entity\User;
use RepositoryBundle\Enum\RoleEnum;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;


class UserDAOTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $userDAO;
    private $logger;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->userDAO = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('repository.userDAO');
        $this->logger = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('logger');
        $logger->notice('Show the log'); // Nothing is in my console.. (I configure Monolog to display in the console)
    }

    public function testTRUC()
    {
        //Stupid test but not executed !!!???
        $i = 1;
        $this->assertTrue($i == 1);
    }

    public function testCreate()
    {
        //Real test but not executed !!!???
        $user1 = new User();
        $user1->setName("TestName");
        $user1->setEmail("TestEmail");
        $user1->setPassword("TestPassword");
        $user1->setMemberNumber(12345);
        $user1->setAdmin(true);
        $user1->setRole(RoleEnum::User);

        $user1 = $UserDAO->save($user1);

        $this->assertTrue($user1->getId() > 0);
        $this->assertEquals("TestName", $user1->getName());
        $this->assertEquals("TestEmail", $user1->getEmail());
        $this->assertEquals("TestPassword", $user1->getPassword());
        $this->assertEquals(12345, $user1->getMemberNumber());
        $this->assertEquals(true, $user1->isAdmin());
        $this->assertEquals(RoleEnum::User, $user1->getRole());
    }
```

phpunit.xml.dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
         backupGlobals="false"
         verbose="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <php>
        <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

When I execute the command :

[A screen of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wORfU.png)

Thanks for your help. I'm new with Symfony and PHPUnit and I lost a lot of time with this kind of problems..

Comment: It's pretty obvious that your tests are not being executed in spite of your comment about the use statement.  Confirm with a die in setup and then see what you did to the phpunit xml file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Confirm with a die in setup"
I'm sur that the PHPunit is correctly configurated because if I remove all line about the service userDAO, it works fine.

Nevertheless I add these informations

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but your test is located in `src\RepositoryBundle\Tests\DAO` and you are executing phpunit on folder app...

Try `phpunit`(*Edit* of course c option requires an argument :/) and it should work.

You configuration is configured to look up '../src/*Bundle/Tests'. If you provide the app folder as the place to to look up test, then your configuration won't be considered.

Comment: When I execute `phpunit -c` I must tell where is the config file that the command need to read. And this config file is in app/ .
I'm sure that the test are found by the phpunit command because with the same configuration but whithout setUp() and without any call to $UserDAO->...  the tests are excuted.

So the problem come from the call at my service. But I don't know why.

Comment: Ok maybe the wrong approach, I corrected my answer, offcourse if you provide -c option you have to provide a config file.

Comment: Have you tried to debug  the setUp()? I mean, maybe trie first to just uncomment the dao service. If it is working you have definitly a problem with your service(what it sounds like).